# Best way to compare date from source to target

Tags: informatica

I'm looking to sync Salesforce to an sql table with informatica cloud. I need to compare the date in the salesforce object against a date in the sql table before updating the sf record. If the createdDate of the sf record is within 10 days of the startdate in sql then update sf with the sql record, otherwise ignore. I've done some syncing in the past but never needed to have criteria from source and target. I usually just need to handle the query in sql. Hoping to find a relatively uncomplicated way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Informatica's DATE_DIFF function

https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-1/_transformation-language-reference_powercenter_10-1_ditamap/dates/understanding_date_arithmetic.html